# ModelDefinitionException("At least 1 primary key is required.") even when Primary key is already defined

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlengine

I am using Cqlalchemy to interact with Cassandra db using Python.
While running the application, I am facing error

```
raise ModelDefinitionException("At least 1 primary key is required.")
cassandra.cqlengine.models.ModelDefinitionException: At least 1 primary key is required.
```

Models looks like:

```
class Model1(db.Model):
    id = db.columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4),
    type = db.columns.Text(required=False)
    user_id = db.columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Where `db = CQLAlchemy()`

Cassandra table DDL is:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace1.model1 (
    id uuid,
    user_id uuid,
    type text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, user_id)
)
```

EDIT:
I went to debug it at cqlengine/models.py file level.
What I noticed was all the columns were being captured as instance of `tuple`

```
 'id': (<cqlengine.columns.UUID object at 0x7f86b2c7c940>,), 'user_id': (<cqlengine.columns.UUID object at 0x7f86b2c7c9b0>,)
```

And cqlengine filters out keys from `attrs` key by checking if its a type of `columns.Column`.

```
column_definitions = [(k, v) for k, v in attrs.items() if isinstance(v, columns.Column)]
```

[Github link for cqlengine/models.py](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine/blob/7079eaf7071cbf5a045e1d1ab57f6d1b5ba3f9dc/cqlengine/models.py#L704)

That's why its actually not able to get any column and hence says no primary key defined.

Any idea why columns are being picked as tuple type and not columns.Column?

Thanks

Comment: What is the Cassandra table definition?

Comment: Hi @Aaron. I have added the DDL in question

Comment: the code that you're pointing to is really old, and now merged into Cassandra driver (see warning at https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine) - do you continue to use old version, or you're using Cassandra driver? If later, then what version of it?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt I ported my code to use cqlengine, but it still remains the same.
Still the columns are coming as tuple type only. `(<cassandra.cqlengine.columns.UUID object at 0x7f69d9ffdd68>,)`

Comment: what version of the Python driver?

Comment: version is 3.16.0